# Is there a way to 2 straight edges between nodes?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

Does anyone know a way to get two straight edges between nodes so that both are visible? And with different styles on each?

I have only found ways to get multiple edges with curves; 2 straight edges always hover one another.

Comment: Please desribe the expected result in more detail. It is possible to create multiple straight edges but it's unclear what's your problem with doing so. Best regards

Comment: I want have to striat parallel edges between two nodes. but making them O curve make the 2 edges on top of each other.. so you only see one

Comment: BTW, just to let you know I deleted an answer I had posted yesterday, as it did not apply to creating 'multiple' such edges, which I now realize is what you had asked about.

Comment: Nope, I don't understand what's the problem. Does creating just 2 edges fit your needs? http://jsfiddle.net/ujpwnkth/2/

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice ! Yes I want two strait parralel edges between the same to nodes, not curved tho. In you fiddle I only see one?

Comment: Hi, first I suggest you to use mentions (@) if you want conversations not to stop (I returned here just accidentaly). Second, ok now I understand what you want, you may want to see https://stackoverflow.com/q/48892281/3995261